# What's the correct MySQL query syntax in AWS DataAPI for Aurora SQL Serverless database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an AWS Aurora SQL Serverless database cluster, I enabled DataAPI for it so I can query data from AWS console, it works fine if I do `select * from db.table_name LIMIT 10;`, but it says `Database returned more than the allowed response size limit` if I query without `LIMIT 10`.

From reading AWS doc, it looks like the max response is 1000, so I'm thinking I can query with a `WHERE` staement, so I tried:

```
select * from db.table_name
where `data` == `xxxxx`;
```

It complains:

```
Database error code: 1064. Message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
```

I tried to use a differen quote`' '`, still not working... does anyone know what's the correct syntax here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` is not an operator in SQL.

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/non-typed-operators.html

Also the back-ticks are correct syntax, but I guess you mean for `data` to be a column name and `'xxxxx'` to be a string literal.

Use straight single-quotes for string literals. Use back-ticks only for identifiers.

So your query should probably (I'm extrapolating) look like this:

```
select * from db.table_name
where `data` = 'xxxxx';
```